# Azure Api Management import APIs from swagger

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, swagger, azure-api-management

I use swashbuckle nuget to generate swagger.json for API in asp.net web api project. Generated json has fields called 'tags'.
Swagger ui uses these 'tags' to group api methods. Is it possible to do similar grouping in api management?
Or can I use tags to set Web API URL suffixes automatically somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it's not supported as there is no functionality to tag APIs thus no way to import this information from Swagger. Feel free to suggest a feature at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management, we'll look into supporting that in future.

Answer (score 0):

There is no similar grouping concept in API Management developer portal docs.  I'm not sure what you mean by using tags to set URL suffixes.  Can you give an example?

Comment: adding or importing API users can set this suffix, here is description from publisher portal: "Last part of the API's public URL. This URL will be used by API consumers for sending requests to the web service." So what if set swagger tags as url suffixes? Looks not very good but still how bad this idea is?